# Must I use past tense before 後?

Tags: grammar, tense, aspect

From [this page](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/verb_sequences), I see this sentence:

> **Note**: Be careful of the tense of the verb that comes before 「前」 and 「後」. 「前」 is non-past while 「後」 is always past tense.

I am confused because it is quite weird to disallow the usage of non-past tense before 後. What if I'm talking about the things that I will do tomorrow? For example, which should I use if I want to say "I will go to school after I have breakfast tomorrow"?

> 明日は、朝ご飯を食べ**た**後、学校に行く。
>
> 明日は、朝ご飯を食べ**る**後、学校に行く。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This た doesn't mean "past" but "completion". It isn't unnatural that た which means "completion" is used in things in the future.

So 明日は、朝ご飯を食べた後、学校に行く is correct.

Comment: Oh I see! I thought Japanese had completely changed from using aspects to using tenses! Apparently some parts of it still have the concept of "aspects"! :)

Comment: @Sweeper When I took Japanese in college just a few years ago, we were taught that Japanese uses aspect more than tense, so it seems in general Japanese is still more on the aspect side of things.