# Usage of the verb 続く in past tense

Tags: grammar, tense, aspect

From [this article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011702601000/k10011702601000.html)

> 日本では、スポーツの選手がコーチなどから暴力やパワーハラスメントを受ける問題が**続きました**。
>   The problem of sportsmen receiving violence and harassment from coaches in Japan continued.

I don't understand why 続く is written in the past tense here. If you read the rest of the article there is no suggestion that the harassment has come to an end. I would have written 続いています.

When is it correct to use 続いた and why is it correct in this case?

Edit after @Ringil's comment:
I'm familiar with the idea that た represents completion, and also with ている being a continuation of state. But when I apply these concepts to 続く I get confused.  For example つづいている = "the state of continuing continues". This seems like a tautology. How does 続く differ from 続いている? How can we understand 続いた = "the continuing is complete"? Is this equivalent to もう続かない? Its sounds from @kandyman's comment that this is not the case. His translation of 'has continued' is more what I would think of as 続いてる i.e. we've done some continuing and the state still persists. I've got myself very confused.

Comment: I won't write this as a full reply, but using 続きました implies 'has continued' (despite the fact that ...). Using 続いています would be a statement of mere fact that it is continuing, but using 続きました implies that despite the issue being highlighted in recent scandals, it has still continued to happen. So I would translate the sentence with "has continued" rather than "continued".

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42988/are-japanese-tenses-aspects-in-disguise is related

Answer (score 2):

It's correct to express what happened as "happened". Past tense doesn't necessarily guarantee that something ceased.

In this example, it continues to 日本ユニセフは…考えた, which implies that the former is a trigger to the latter. So, using past tense is more cohesive to the next line.